# Perl matching array across file

Tags: perl

I have a file which looks like this.

In the Perl code, i am using an array `@query = ('A+80', 'A+40', 'A+202', 'B+130', 'B+268', 'B+211', 'A+35');`
What I want to do is: for each element of the array, scan the lines in the file shown below and print out something like this:

```
A+80 - HELIX

A+40 - SHEET

A+202 - HELIX

B+130 - HELIX

B+268 - SHEET

B+211 - SHEET

A+35 - LOOP
```

The logic behind this output is to extract for each entry in array, the first part i.e. A or B, and the second part, i.e. the number associated with the 1st part. Consider the first entry in the array: `A+80`. On the third line of the file the number 80 is lying between 78 (the 6th column) and 90 (the 9th column) and also first alphabet `A` is also matching in both cases. Hence the program prints HELIX for this query.

Consider 2nd element: `A+40`. The 2nd part i.e the number lies in the range as on this line

```
SHEET    2   B 3 ARG A  37  VAL A  43  1
```

i.e. between the numbers listed in columns 7 and 10, and the alphabet matches too. Hence for this entry the output is: SHEET

For other cases, like `B+211`. THe line given below matches the number and the alphabet associated with it.

```
SHEET    2   B 3 ARG A  37  VAL A  43  1
```

Hence the output for this entry is: SHEET

Also, for entries whose alphabet and number associated with it, do not match any of the lines in the file. the code outputs: `A+35 - LOOP`

What is an efficient way to do this in Perl?
Since I am a beginner with Perl, I am as of now splitting each entry in successive array elements, i.e. for `@query`, and matching/comparing the alphabet and number to each of the relevant columns in the lines. But somehow am unable to get the output desired.

Please help...

```
HELIX    1   1 GLY A    9  GLN A   30  1                                  
HELIX    2   2 ASP A   47  ILE A   63  1                                  
HELIX    3   3 GLU A   78  GLU A   90  1                                  
HELIX    4   4 THR A  111  ALA A  117  1                                  
HELIX    5   5 PRO A  120  LYS A  122  5                                  
HELIX    6   6 SER A  129  ARG A  137  1                                  
HELIX    7   7 CYS A  147  THR A  159  1                                  
HELIX    8   8 GLY A  178  ASN A  188  1                                  
HELIX    9   9 LEU A  202  LYS A  208  1                                  
HELIX   10  10 GLY A  224  TRP A  226  5                                  
HELIX   11  11 TYR A  258  GLU A  263  1                                  
HELIX   12  12 VAL A  275  PHE A  294  1                                  
HELIX   13  13 GLY B    9  GLN B   30  1                                  
HELIX   14  14 ASP B   47  ILE B   63  1                                  
HELIX   15  15 GLU B   78  GLU B   90  1                                  
HELIX   16  16 THR B  111  ALA B  117  1                                  
HELIX   17  17 PRO B  120  LYS B  122  5                                  
HELIX   18  18 SER B  129  ARG B  137  1                                  
HELIX   19  19 CYS B  147  THR B  159  1                                  
HELIX   20  20 GLY B  178  TRP B  187  1                                  
HELIX   21  21 LEU B  202  LYS B  208  1                                  
HELIX   22  22 GLY B  224  TRP B  226  5                                  
HELIX   23  23 TYR B  258  GLU B  263  1                                  
HELIX   24  24 GLY B  276  PHE B  294  5                                  
SHEET    1   A 2 GLU A   5  LEU A   7  0                                        
SHEET    2   A 2 PHE A 267  THR A 269  1  
SHEET    1   B 3 LYS A  66  LEU A  72  0                                        
SHEET    2   B 3 ARG A  37  VAL A  43  1  
SHEET    3   B 3 GLY A  96  VAL A  99  1  
SHEET    1   C 4 THR A 191  CYS A 195  0                                        
SHEET    2   C 4 HIS A 167  VAL A 171  1  
SHEET    3   C 4 ILE A 211  VAL A 214  1  
SHEET    4   C 4 ILE A 232  ASP A 235  1             
SHEET    1   D 2 GLU B   5  LEU B   7  0                                        
SHEET    2   D 2 PHE B 267  THR B 269  1  
SHEET    1   E 3 LYS B  66  LEU B  72  0                                        
SHEET    2   E 3 ARG B  37  VAL B  43  1  
SHEET    3   E 3 GLY B  96  VAL B  99  1  
SHEET    1   F 4 THR B 191  CYS B 195  0                                        
SHEET    2   F 4 HIS B 167  VAL B 171  1  
SHEET    3   F 4 ILE B 211  VAL B 214  1  
SHEET    4   F 4 ILE B 232  ASP B 235  1  
SHEET    1   G 2 ASN B 239  PRO B 242  0                                        
SHEET    2   G 2 ARG B 250  VAL B 253 -1
```

Comment: The language is called Perl or perl not PERL.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. First take a look at the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and please show your code. It says more than any description. And you should be specific what your actual problem is. Where are you stuck? With this information we are more likely to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The program below seems to do what you need. It reads data from within the source file using the `DATA` file handle for convenience: you must arrange to open and read the appropriate data file.

The entirety of the file is read into memory for straightforward access. If the file is enormous (say, hundreds of megabytes) then this approach may be inappropriate and you will have to come back for more help.

The records vary in length, so the algorithm locates the relevant fields relative to the first three-letter field found.

The hash `%categories` contains all of the required file data. It is indexed by the key letter - `A` or `B` here - and the value of each element is an array of anonymous hashes containing the `label` (column 1), the `letter`, and the `start` and `end` of the range covered by each record.

Building the output is straightforward, and uses `map` and `grep` to find the 'label' of all the relevant entries in the hash. If none are found the text `"LOOP"` is added as a default.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @query = qw/ A+80 A+40 A+202 B+130 B+268 B+211 A+35 /;

my %categories;

while (<DATA>) {
  next unless /\S/;
  my @data = split;
  my @indices = grep $data[$_] =~ /^[A-Z]{3}$/, 0 .. $#data;
  my %info;
  @info{qw/ label letter start end /} = @data[ 0, $indices[0]+1, $indices[0]+2, $indices[1]+2 ];
  push @{ $categories{$info{letter}} }, \%info;
}

for my $item (@query) {
  my ($letter, $value) = split /\+/, $item;
  my @matches = map $_->{label},
      grep { $value >= $_->{start} and $value <= $_->{end} }
      @{ $categories{$letter} };
  @matches = ('LOOP') unless @matches;
  warn qq(Multiple categories for query "$item") unless @matches == 1;
  printf "%s - %s\n", $item, $_ for @matches 
}

__DATA__
HELIX    1   1 GLY A    9  GLN A   30  1                                  
HELIX    2   2 ASP A   47  ILE A   63  1                                  
HELIX    3   3 GLU A   78  GLU A   90  1                                  
HELIX    4   4 THR A  111  ALA A  117  1                                  
HELIX    5   5 PRO A  120  LYS A  122  5                                  
HELIX    6   6 SER A  129  ARG A  137  1                                  
HELIX    7   7 CYS A  147  THR A  159  1                                  
HELIX    8   8 GLY A  178  ASN A  188  1                                  
HELIX    9   9 LEU A  202  LYS A  208  1                                  
HELIX   10  10 GLY A  224  TRP A  226  5                                  
HELIX   11  11 TYR A  258  GLU A  263  1                                  
HELIX   12  12 VAL A  275  PHE A  294  1                                  
HELIX   13  13 GLY B    9  GLN B   30  1                                  
HELIX   14  14 ASP B   47  ILE B   63  1                                  
HELIX   15  15 GLU B   78  GLU B   90  1                                  
HELIX   16  16 THR B  111  ALA B  117  1                                  
HELIX   17  17 PRO B  120  LYS B  122  5                                  
HELIX   18  18 SER B  129  ARG B  137  1                                  
HELIX   19  19 CYS B  147  THR B  159  1                                  
HELIX   20  20 GLY B  178  TRP B  187  1                                  
HELIX   21  21 LEU B  202  LYS B  208  1                                  
HELIX   22  22 GLY B  224  TRP B  226  5                                  
HELIX   23  23 TYR B  258  GLU B  263  1                                  
HELIX   24  24 GLY B  276  PHE B  294  5                                  
SHEET    1   A 2 GLU A   5  LEU A   7  0                                        
SHEET    2   A 2 PHE A 267  THR A 269  1  
SHEET    1   B 3 LYS A  66  LEU A  72  0                                        
SHEET    2   B 3 ARG A  37  VAL A  43  1  
SHEET    3   B 3 GLY A  96  VAL A  99  1  
SHEET    1   C 4 THR A 191  CYS A 195  0                                        
SHEET    2   C 4 HIS A 167  VAL A 171  1  
SHEET    3   C 4 ILE A 211  VAL A 214  1  
SHEET    4   C 4 ILE A 232  ASP A 235  1             
SHEET    1   D 2 GLU B   5  LEU B   7  0                                        
SHEET    2   D 2 PHE B 267  THR B 269  1  
SHEET    1   E 3 LYS B  66  LEU B  72  0                                        
SHEET    2   E 3 ARG B  37  VAL B  43  1  
SHEET    3   E 3 GLY B  96  VAL B  99  1  
SHEET    1   F 4 THR B 191  CYS B 195  0                                        
SHEET    2   F 4 HIS B 167  VAL B 171  1  
SHEET    3   F 4 ILE B 211  VAL B 214  1  
SHEET    4   F 4 ILE B 232  ASP B 235  1  
SHEET    1   G 2 ASN B 239  PRO B 242  0                                        
SHEET    2   G 2 ARG B 250  VAL B 253 -1
```

***output***

```
A+80 - HELIX
A+40 - SHEET
A+202 - HELIX
B+130 - HELIX
B+268 - SHEET
B+211 - SHEET
A+35 - LOOP
```